# windows Service / Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a application here that should automatically deploy the web service on local server(not in IIS). It is ok with running like windows service. Has any one help with Idea??

Answer (score 5):

you can use Windows Communication Foundation `(WCF)` and host it on windows service

check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx#Y400) out.

or you can use Web Services Enhancements for Microsoft .NET Framework `(WSE)` to host normal asp.net web service on windows service or console application.

check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529311.aspx) out.

Ones you have created one of above project you need to create setup project to [install windows service project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx).

Comment: Many Thanks for your guidance, I'm near to implement this.Can you please provide me link that you provided for WCF 1st one it is not working I'm not able to open it.